# Laravel localstorage item fetch in Controller

Tags: javascript, laravel, local-storage

In Laravel,Is there any way to get localstorage items in controller.I want to return this items in view blade. My localstorage item looks like .

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I will suggest you to get the value from the localStorage with javascript using `localStorage.getItem('myItem')` and then store it as a cookie using `document.cookie = "name=value"`. You will now be able to access it from your laravel controller using `$_COOKIE['cookieName']`.

Example:

`Javascript`

```
//define a function to set cookies
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
   var expires = "";
   if (days) {
       var date = new Date();
       date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
       expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
   }
   document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
}

//get your item from the localStorage
var myItem = localStorage.getItem('myItem');
setCookie('cookieName', myItem, 7);
```

`PHP`

```
$myItem = '';

if(isset($_COOKIE['cookieName'])) {
    $myItem = $_COOKIE['cookieName'];
}
```

Comment: You should use laravel to get the cookie Cookie::get('theme')

Answer (score 3):

You can pass them from javascript with some event. You cannot just retrieve them in controller, because its server side.

Answer (score 1):

I will extend @kamgas answer

You could set it in a cookie instead of local storage, which will allow Laravel to read the cookie

To fetch the cookie with Laravel you should use:

```
Cookie::get('mycookie')
```

Since Laravel by default only allow Laravel to read Laravel encrypted cookies you will need to set an exception in the `App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies` middleware class

```
protected $except = [
    'mycookie',
];
```

Answer (score -2):

You cannot do that in laravel controller, but you can do it in blade. So retrieve the data in blade and pass the data to controller.

Comment: This answer is a little bit gibberish. There's no such thing as "in blade" as a distinct concept, it's still all server side. And blade can't "pass data to the controller", it's what gets returned FROM the controller.